# Why speech recognition works in web page, but in electron not

Tags: c#, electron, blazor, electron.net

I have a simple speech recognition app.

If I run it using a web server the microphone it is working.

[image]

If I run it using *electron* the microphone it is not working. I would mention that the problem is not my *microphone* because in logs I can see that microphone is working.

I don't know why the same thing in electron does not working.

I would mention that the same thing worked some days ago. I didn't change any package or something like this. This is pretty strange what it's happened.

Comment: are you using the internal webkitSpeechRecognition / Chrome Speech API?

Comment: @Tobias, I used this library https://github.com/jsakamoto/Toolbelt.Blazor.SpeechRecognition

Comment: @Tobias, I also tried with native speech recognition from browser. The behaviour is that after clicking "Start", it is automatically called the "onend" function.

Answer (score 1):

blazor SpeechRecognition uses internal browser webkitSpeechRecognition
[image]

this is not available in electron...[see here](https://discuss.atom.io/t/webkitspeechrecognition-google-webkit-speech-api-throws-network-error-in-electron-app/27958)

as in the commits descripted i found today a post on github where it shows that this was a bug and it should be fixed in electron version 9.x...
i tested this with version 9.0.4, just a minute ago, but getting the same result as in version 8.x.

Comment: Then how can we explain that this worked until two days ago ?

Comment: What did you change since then ? :)

Comment: @CaiusJard, I didn't change anything. Just a VS 2019 upgrade, but regarding the versions of the libraries ElectronNET and Blazor Speech Recognition they remained the same

Comment: @CaiusJard, I also implement the native speech recognition in javascript and I encountered the same behaviour. In the browser it is working, after use electron does not.

Comment: I'm a bit confused; do you mean that the speech recognition works in e.g. chrome, and then you use your app in electron and it doesnt work in electron but when you switch back to chrome it is also now not working in chrome (electron killed chrome?
)

Comment: I mean that not working in electron. In the browser everytime it's working

Comment: i dont know what you have done...but if you get this working many people including me
would be very grateful to you. I also tried it very long and intensively, but after a lot of searching, i and others think google turned off support for command line tools like electron

Comment: interesting post here...maybe try with electron 9.x
https://github.com/electron/electron/issues/23813

Comment: have you found a fix?